# How do I perform hit test in TreeView for TreeViewItem?

Tags: c#, treeview, silverlight-4.0, hittest, treeviewitem

I have a *System.Windows.Controls.TreeView* in my project, and when the user right click in it, I'm displaying a context menu. Since the context menu is built dynamically, I need to know the *System.Windows.Controls.TreeViewItem* that the mouse is hovering over.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visit [this link](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/CS/silverlight_161/f/78/p/83528/233113.aspx) and [here you can download libs for using ContextMenu](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/CS/announcements/b/c1_gregl-personal/archive/2010/06/14/prerelease-build-77-available.aspx)

Comment: I don't quite understand this code I'm afraid since I'm new to Silverlight. Would you mind explaining how I use it? Thanks.